# Rails : CSS won't change unless I precompile locally in development

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

My CSS won't change when I view it in the browser unless I precompile locally with `rake assets:precompile`.

Any ideas on how to remove this behavior? Do you need more files?

Here is my development.rb :

```
Mobile::Application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
config.cache_classes = false

# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
config.whiny_nils = true

# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
config.active_support.deprecation = :log

# Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true

   end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the `public/assets` folder. The files in the `public/assets` folder will be preferentially loaded over the ones that are in the `app/assets` folder.

Once deleted, you should be able to develop locally using the files in `app/assets`.